# Make JPopupMenu NOT close on item selection

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem, jpopupmenu

Here's what I want to do. I am making a popup that suggests words, 10 at a time, with the option to display the next 10 suggestions. I designed this as a JPopupMenu with 11 items; 10 suggestions and one "Show more..." option.

[image]

The code that is run on the "Show more..." removes all the previous items, and adds the new ones (simple enough).

The problem is that when I press "Show more..." the JPopupMenu closes (as I suppose is the default behaviour). I have tried working my way around this, even by creating a whole new popup and display it on the same location.

Is there a simple way to make a JPopupMenu NOT disappear when pressing one of its items?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: for better help sooner post an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about empty `JFrame` with your `JPopup` with `JMenuItems`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using this for checkbox items:

```
import javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.MenuSelectionManager;
import javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicCheckBoxMenuItemUI;

public class StayOpenCheckBoxMenuItemUI extends BasicCheckBoxMenuItemUI {

    @Override
    protected void doClick(MenuSelectionManager msm) {
        menuItem.doClick(0);
    }

    public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent c) {
        return new StayOpenCheckBoxMenuItemUI();
    }

}
```

Then, register it:

```
myJCheckBoxMenuItem.setUI(new StayOpenCheckBoxMenuItemUI());
```

Depending on what type of menu item your 'Show more' item is, similar solution should work. Just subclass the proper UI instead of `BasicCheckBoxMenuItemUI`.

Comment: That approach seems to work when you press the popup item with the mouse, but NOT when using the accelerator hotkey (which is what I would like as well).